# How to display certain comments stored on a database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've created a form for a comment box that I'm going to use on a couple of different pages. It sends the data to a table called "comments" in my database that has columns "id" "author" "body" "created" and "page_name". I'm new to php and I'm trying to figure out how to just display the comments that have the same "page_name" value as the current page.

To get the "page_name", I used this code in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_name" value="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" />
```

This is the code I'm building to display the comments:

```
<div id="comments">
  <?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
    <div class="comment" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
        <div class="author">
          <b><?php echo htmlentities($comment->author); ?>:</b>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-info" style="font-size: 0.8em;">
          <?php echo datetime_to_text($comment->created); ?>
        </div>
      <div class="body">
          <?php echo strip_tags($comment->body, '<strong><em><p>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php if(empty($comments)) { echo "No Comments."; } ?>
</div>
```

I'm just not sure how to tell the page to display only the comments that have the same "page_name" value as the page the user is on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is your database query that gets the comments? You _could_ add a simple `if` statement inside the loop to check the comments `page_name` value against the current `page_name`, but you should really edit the database query so that only the relevant comments are loaded in the first place.

Comment: What is your data retrieving query.

Comment: you need to do it by query, apply filter on query based on page name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query the data corresponding to the url like.

For database connection use the code below:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$db_con=mysql_connect('servername','db username','dbpassword');
if (!$db_con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$connection_string=mysql_select_db('db name',$db_con);
?>
```

For query use the code:

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from comments where page_name='".$url."'");
while($result=mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
echo $result[0]."<br>".$result[1]."<br>";          // echo all values that are needed for displaying. You can do the coding for displaying formatted values inside this loop.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it'll do what I need. I'm just now sure what the line "echo $result[0]."<br>".$result[1]."<br">;" means. When I tried putting it in, it warns me about a syntax error, but since I don't understand that line, I don't know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Echo is for printing a text/value in php. Here if there are total 3 records satisying the query in the table, then the while loop will execute 3 times. ie, it will execute until there is records satisfying the condition. Each time, the record will be stored in the variable $result, so inorder to get each field values for a record we have to call the resultset, here, $result with the subscript as the number of field. If id is the first field then, we should use $result[0] for getting the id.

Comment: We can print html tags with PHP by enclosing it inside "". So <?php echo "<br>"; ?> will produce a break element.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, I have to know how many comments I want displayed before they are displayed? But I wouldn't know many there are going to be ahead of time since people can add comments whenever...

Comment: You don't need to know the number of comments initially. The loop will execute as far there is value in it.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now, thanks for explaining. Do you know why it's telling me there is a syntax error though? (I'm using Dreamweaver and it's highlighting that line with that error message)

Comment: I also get an error on mysql_fetchRow. It says it's an undefined function. When I looked it up on the php manual, it says the extention is set to be removed

Comment: sorry for the mistake..it is mysql_fetch_row

Comment: Thanks, that error goes away, but I still have the syntax error for the "echo $result" line of code. I think you missed putting a > at the end of the second <br>. I added it in on my end, but I still get the syntax error either way